# Linux: Implicit function declaration error even though function is present

Tags: c, linux, unix, linux-kernel, kernel

I am trying to call a custom function from the `linux/fs/ext2/file.c` file as follows:

```
printk(KERN_ALERT "Count: %i\n", getValue());
```

I have added the declaration and definition of the `getValue()` function at the top of `file.c`

```
static int getValue(void);

static int getValue(void) {
        return 123;
}
```

However, my `printk` call is giving the following when compiling:

```
fs/ext2/file.c: In function ‘ext2_fsync’:
fs/ext2/file.c:162:52: error: implicit declaration of function ‘getValue’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  162 |         printk(KERN_ALERT "Count: %i\n", getValue());
      |                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/printk.h:436:33: note: in definition of macro ‘printk_index_wrap’
  436 |                 _p_func(_fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__);                           \
      |                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~
fs/ext2/file.c:162:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘printk’
  162 |         printk(KERN_ALERT "Count: %i\n", getValue());
      |         ^~~~~~
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:249: fs/ext2/file.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:466: fs/ext2] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:1846: fs] Error 2
```

I am able to run this code separately but when building the kernel, I get the error mentioned above. How would I fix this?

Comment: "I have added the declaration and definition of the `getValue()` function at the top of `file.c`" - If you put your declaration [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.19.9/source/fs/ext2/file.c#L33), then this part of the code is not parsed unless configuration option `CONFIG_FS_DAX` is set.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Yes that is where I have placed the function. Is there an alternative way to get it to parse other than setting `CONFIG_FS_DAX`?

Comment: Just place it **outside** of the lines between `#ifdef`-`#endif`.